# Appending information to the first second and third line of a .txt to create a database of scraped information python 3.5

Tags: python, database, csv, web-scraping, append

I want to be able to take and append information I have scraped and add it to a .txt to create a database to allow for quicker querying of IP addresses I have already searched.

The file has 3 lines, and the information in the lines are separated by commas, which allows me to open it in Excel and use pandas to easily read and check to see if the information is in there.

My problem is being able to append new information to the first line, second line, and third line of the .txt file. I want it to look like this:

```
ip,ip,ip,ip 

websiteinfo1,websiteinfo1,websiteinfo1,websiteinfo1

websiteinfo2,websiteinfo2,websiteinfo2,websiteinfo2
```

When a new IP is searched and info pulled, I want to be able to append it to the corresponding line.

```
ip,ip,ip,ip,newip

websiteinfo1,websiteinfo1,websiteinfo1,websiteinfo1,newwebsiteinfo1

websiteinfo2,websiteinfo2,websiteinfo2,websiteinfo2,newwensiteinfo2
```

Comment: It's a text file. If you're going to add something in the middle, you'll need to rewrite the whole thing. Easy to do with just 3 lines. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Why not change the format to ip, info1, info2 for each row, then you could just append to the file. All your existing tools to analyse it could be easily refactored with a transposition.

Comment: Ricardo -I have been looking at a few different way to do it but nothing seems to work how I would like to.
wwii - I was thinking of that but I like how pandas does the interfacing and makes it easy to go through the code by columns. I would be looking for information by the ip address associates with it.